# focus() does not work at all

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I try to `focus()` an input in a Bootstrap modal, but nothing seems to work. I have tried the `setTimeout` and the `tabindex` fixes, but nothing.

Even when I run it in the console:

```
$("#inpProperty").focus();

$("#inpProperty")[0].focus();
```

it doesn't focus. I am using Firefox 53.0, 64 bit on Fedora.

This is the modal:

```
<div id="mdlAddProperty" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Property</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="alert alert-danger collapse" id="divAlert">
            <a href="#" class="collapse" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <span id="spnMessage"></span>
        </div>

        <p>Property Name:</p>
        <p><input class="input" id="inpProperty" tabindex="1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" tabindex="2" onclick="btnAddProperty_Click()">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="3" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** it works one time in Chrome, zero times in Firefox.

Comment: a code sample please... lol

Comment: did u surround the code with an DOM ready event?

Comment: @Nixivious the code is run from an event handler. But as I said, even in the console I cannot get it to focus.

Comment: Did you write the `focus` inside `shown.bs.modal` event of the modal ?

Comment: @Panther tried it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Bootstrap Modal events you can use:

[image]

Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Also if you are running js at console you need use this(open modal first):

`jQuery("#inpProperty").focus();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myBtn").click(function() {
    $("#mdlAddProperty").modal("show");
  });
  $("#mdlAddProperty").on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#inpProperty").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Events - shown.bs.modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="mdlAddProperty" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Property</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="alert alert-danger collapse" id="divAlert">
            <a href="#" class="collapse" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <span id="spnMessage"></span>
          </div>

          <p>Property Name:</p>
          <p>
            <input class="input" id="inpProperty" tabindex="1">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" tabindex="2" onclick="btnAddProperty_Click()">Create</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="3" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This makes no difference.

Comment: That works, yet I cannot get it running in my own modal code. Tried almost everything .....

Comment: Apparently, it was all-of-the-above. I added a timeout, and it works now.

Comment: @BartFriederichs not a very good practice to use a timeout if you could find the cause.

Comment: Agreed, but many other answers suggest this as well. It will do for now, might fix it for real later.

Comment: @BartFriederichs true, there is nothing timeout can't fix in javascript lol

Answer (score 0):

If you need to focus it in just the beginnig you can add `autofocus` event on the html element you want to focus in.

```
<div id="mdlAddProperty" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Property</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="alert alert-danger collapse" id="divAlert">
            <a href="#" class="collapse" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <span id="spnMessage"></span>
        </div>

        <p>Property Name:</p>
        <p><input class="input" id="inpProperty" tabindex="1" autofocus></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" tabindex="2" onclick="btnAddProperty_Click()">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="3" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But if you want to do it with jQuery you need to surround your code with `$(document).ready(function());`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inpProperty").focus();
    $("#inpProperty")[0].focus();
});
```

Comment: Still nothing. And I want to focus when the modal shows, not when the document loads.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet? so we can test it out in real-time